# Can't modify text font size on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, resize

I found a post about modifying text size specifically for mobile in a specific div, like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.news {
    font-size: 5px;
 }
 }
```

I can't get that to work however for the site I'm messing with. I'd like the font size to be smaller when opened on mobile. While I wonder if I have to set a viewport meta in the html, every time I do this A, it doesn't fix it, B, it totally destroys the balance of my site, clipping tons of information, which I really don't like. So, the only way I'm going to be able to use a viewport right now, is if it doesn't mess with the zoom factor at all. Not sure if that's the issue though.
Really appreciate any help on this. Full code:

css:

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

body{
text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: 1;
font-family: 'rationale';
background:black;

}




#newsusa {

position: absolute; /*makes it relative to the html element, (the first           
positioned element).*/
 width: 100%; /*makes the element 100%, to center it. */
 left: 0px;
 top: 200px;


 }




 .news {
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
}   


li {
list-style-type: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.news {
    font-size: 0.8em;!important;
}
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 280px) {

.news {
    font-size: 0.8em;!important;
}
}
```

xhtml:

```
<?php include 'global.php';?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobiletest.css">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com     

/css?family=Iceland|Rationale|Quantico|VT323|Dorsa' rel='stylesheet'      
 type='text/css'>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3    
/jquery.min.js'></script>


 <div id="newsusa">

<h1 class="appear-later">News</h1>

<div class="spacer1">
</div>

<div class="news">
<ul><?php outputValueFromCache('usnews', 'ignore'); ?></ul>
</div>


<div class="spacer2">
</div>

<h1 class="appear-later">Tech</h1>

<div class="spacer1">
</div>

<div class="news">
<ul><?php outputValueFromCache('usatechnews', 'ignore'); ?></ul>
</div>

<div class="spacer2">
</div>

<h1>Business</h1>

<div class="spacer1">
</div>

<div class="news">
<ul><?php outputValueFromCache('usamoneynews', 'ignore'); ?></ul>
</div>

 </div>






 </html>
```

Comment: try to use `font-size: 5px;!important` and work with `em` like `font-size: 0.8em;!important`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to add the

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

to your header. If you consider the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            .page-header{
                font-size: 16px;
                color: red;
            }
            @media (max-width: 430px) {
                .page-header{
                    font-size:100px;
                    color: green;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="page-header">Hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The media query only works once you have the viewport meta tag defined. I know that's probably not what you want to hear, but I think that's your solution.

Comment: With the exception being media queries.

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried doing that, not seeing a difference yet. Wonder what else I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try @media (max-width: 768px). If you get this to work, you won't need the !importants which will save a lot of headaches down the road.

Comment: no luck. wondering if you have access to a very basic example of modifying font size through like gitnub or something? All I need is one working example to see how it's done, and what I'm doing wrong. Amazingly, it's extremely hard to find a basic example like this on the internet. Been trying